# Why is this specific function returning 'none'; i'm trying to demonstrate a growing list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, loops, append

I want to see the list in realtime growing and when its done I want to query the appended list via indices.

```
l=[]
def GrowingList(list):
    try:
        import random
        while True:
            rlist=lambda: print([random.randint(0,12)])
            list.append(rlist())
            print(list)
        return GrowingList(list)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Here is a transcript:

```
Grown list
[None]
Grown list
[None, None]
Grown list
[None, None, None]
Grown list
[None, None, None, None]
```

When I query the new compiled list it shows 'none' for every index:

```
>>> l
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

I am new to programming so just chill. This list is just a practice function of how lists can be automatically grown. 'Grown list' is just a example of what I want to put within the list.

Comment: Why is the `import random` statement inside the `while` loop. Also, your `lambda` function looks off.

Comment: It's also not clear what your code is attempting to do and what the expected output should be. Please [edit] your question to clarify what's happening and where you are stuck. The lambda (obviously) returns `None`; what were you expecting, and why? How is it supposed to exit the endless loop?

Comment: A growing list is a pretty straight forward question. I was expecting there to be the random numbers between 0,12 to be appended to the list that is inputted into the function. When the inputted list is printed, i want to see the updated list.

Comment: The lambda does obviously return none, but, maybe a constructive comment would have been to explain how its wrong and what would be a better alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using print in lambda which will return None. Also your return is having a recursion which is not necessary.

edit : you can remove the complete lambda part and directly append the random value to list.

You can use below modified code :

```
import random
l=[]
count=1
def GrowingList(list):
    try:
        count=1

        while True:
            rlist=random.randint(0,12)
            list.append(rlist)
            print(list)
            #below three line is added to break the code after 10 iteration you can remove them if you want to break on keyboard interrupt.  
            count+=1
            if count > 10:
                break
        return list

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

output:

```
[1, 10]
[1, 10, 8]
[1, 10, 8, 11]
[1, 10, 8, 11, 2]
[1, 10, 8, 11, 2, 10]
[1, 10, 8, 11, 2, 10, 12]
[1, 10, 8, 11, 2, 10, 12, 5]
[1, 10, 8, 11, 2, 10, 12, 5, 0]
[1, 10, 8, 11, 2, 10, 12, 5, 0, 8]
[1, 10, 8, 11, 2, 10, 12, 5, 0, 8, 8]
```

Comment: I appreciate the constructive feedback. I thought I had to use lambda because  using rlist=random.randint(0,12) outside of a function did not work so I thought lambda was the only way for some reason.

Comment: Call to random should be in the function as you are modifying the value in the loop.